# Hide a button once a php input field $row has a value?

Tags: javascript, php, hide

I am trying to hide a create account button if a value is already existing in the database. I only want the button to show if the Customer Number - `'.$row["custno"].'` field is empty.

I have tried hide/show and toggle using JS but I can't get it to only show the button if the field value of Customer Number - `'.$row["custno"].'` is empty. My last attempt was PHP but now I don't see the customer number or the button.

PHP Code

```
        echo '  
        <div class="as-objecttitle">Create Customer Number</div>';

        if(isset($_POST['custno'])){    
echo '
        <p>Customer Number - '.$row["custno"].' </p>
        <p><a class="as-mainbtn"  href="eappt_accountcreate.php?apptno=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($apptno); ?>">Create Account</a></p>'; }
```

Javascript Code

```
         <?php

       if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     // output data of each row
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


    echo '  <div class="as-objecttitle">Create Customer Number</div>
        <p><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()"           

       checked> Customer Number - '.$row["custno"].' </p>
        <p><i>If a customer number is listed, an account has already been  

         created.</i></p>
        <br>        
        <p id="text" style="display:none"><a class="as-mainbtn"  

         href="eappt_accountcreate.php?apptno=<?php echo 

         htmlspecialchars($apptno); ?>">Create Account</a></p>';



}

        } else {
            echo "";
          }

              mysqli_close($conn);
             ?>

            <script>
              function myFunction() {
              var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
                 var text = document.getElementById("text");
           if (checkBox.checked == true){
         text.style.display = "block";
              } else {
            text.style.display = "none";
               }
              }
                </script>
```

Using the JS method the user has to check the box to show the button. I want the button to be hidden if the Customer Number - `'.$row["custno"].'` is displaying and showing if the Customer Number - `'.$row["custno"].'` is empty. Not the best solution.

Thank you in advance for any recommendations you have.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use javascript here. You can try by using [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if (empty($row['custno']) {
    echo '<a href="..">Create Account</a>';
} else {
    echo 'Customer Number - '. $row['custno'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist but for some reason your suggestion is giving me a blank screen. I used the empty reference you provide and played with the code and was able to come up with this      `echo '<p>CustomeNumber - '.$row["custno"].' </p>';
     if(empty($row['custno'])){ 
     echo '<p><a class="as-mainbtn"  href="eappt_accountcreate.php?apptno='.$row['apptno'].'">Create Account</a></p>'; } ` It works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this condition,

```
if($row['custno']) != ''){
echo "'Customer Number - '.$row['custno']";
}
else
{
echo "< ahref="">Your button</a>
}
```

Let me know if it is working for you. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get mine to work. This also worked, so thank you for the add.